# Are we supposed to initialize variables in JS, regardless of a "value" being set in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I started using HTML and CSS a while back, but I started implementing JS only about a couple of weeks ago. I understand JS independently, along with HMTL and CSS. Now that I have to put them together, I don't understand the implementation of JS-- specifically with variables and manipulating them.

I want to increase, decrease, or represent the changes (e.g., Moves left = 10 => Moves left = 9), but my code doesn't work. Are there specific concepts I need to understand besides "knowing JS basics?" Leaving the code below.

HTML, which only includes the main section:

```
<section class="game">
        <!--Title -->
        <div class="title">Rock Paper Scissor</div>

        <!--Display Score of player and computer -->
        <div class="score">
          <div class="playerScore">
            <h2>Player</h2>
            <p class="p-count count">0</p>
          </div>
          <div class="computerScore">
            <h2>Computer</h2>
            <p class="c-count count">0</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="move">Choose your move</div>

        <!--Number of moves left before game ends -->
        <div class="movesleft">Moves Left: 10</div>

        <!--Options available to player to play game -->
        <div class="options">
          <button class="rock">Rock</button>
          <button class="paper">Paper</button>
          <button class="scissor">Scissors</button>
        </div>

        <!--Final result of game -->
        <div class="result"></div>

        <!--Reload the game -->
        <button class="reload">Reload Game?</button>
      </section>
```

JS, which includes where I want my HTML values to update:

```
const game = () => {
    let playerScore = document.getElementsByClassName('p-count count'); // At the start of the game the player & computer scores will = 0
    let computerScore = document.getElementsByClassName('c-count count');
    let moves = 0; // Start of gaming... total moves will equal 0, so this will initialize it since both the scores are already initalized at 0.

    playGame();
};

const playGame = () => {
    let playerOptions = [document.getElementsByClassName('rock'), document.getElementsByClassName('paper'), document.getElementsByClassName('scissors')];
    let computerOptions = [document.getElementsByClassName('rock'), document.getElementsByClassName('paper'), document.getElementsByClassName('scissors')];

    playerOptions.forEach(addEventListener("click", function(){
        moves++; // This says "we will add 1 to the total moves made." This will affect the moves variable in the game function.
        let movesLeft = document.getElementById('movesleft'); // Calls the movesleft div-class
        return movesLeft - moves; // Begins the subtraction of moves from the starting amount
    }));
    
    let computerSelection = computerOptions[Math.floor((Math.random) * computerOptions.length)] // Within the shared options, this will generate a random number between 0 -
    // - & 2 to represent the options within the array (rock, paper, scissors)

    winner();
    gameOver();

};

const winner = (playerOptions, computerOptions) => {
    if (playerOptions[0] & computerOptions[2]) {
        playerScore++; // Rock beats scissors
    } else if (playerOptions[1] && computerOptions[0]) {
        playerScore++; // Paper beats rock
    } else if (playerOptions[2] && computerOptions[2]) {
        playerScore++; // Scissors beats paper
    } else {
        computerScore++;
    } // Checking player's input to see if was a round-winnable move. 
};
```

Comment: There's a bunch of issues here. The first crucial line is `let playerScore = document.getElementsByClassName('p-count count');` 1. The variable is declared inside a function, so only exists inside, it cannot be used in other functions 2. `getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of nodes, as the name implies, so you would have to append `[0]` to get the first match 3. if you do that, you only have the <p> element itself, not the text inside; for that you would have to append `.innerText` (then parse it into an integer)

Comment: Just skimmed your code, and first thing that caught my eye is that `getElementsByClassName` returns list of elements, not a single element, but you are trying use `playerScore` as if it was a single element.

Comment: I'll also advise against using arrow functions declared as consts. This has no advantage whatsoever and in fact a serious downside: you cannot call those functions before they are declared.

Comment: As for the gist of the question: try to regard HTML (or rather: the DOM) as an interface between a program and the user (because that's exactly what it is). Which means that you should 1. keep the entire app state in variables (and initialize them accordingly) 2. process player input (change variables, etc) 3. update the DOM to reflect the changes to these variables. This also gets rid of the awkward reading of values from a structured document. Basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/7qLs9vpj/

Comment: @ChrisG So getElements is grabbing entire elements within that div, which are h2 and p elements? I looked up the differences between querySelector and the getElements, but didn't really understand it. What is your recommendation is this topic?

Comment: The function is `document.getElementsByClassName` and you pass a class (e.g. "p-count") to it. The function returns a list of all elements that have that class. The list has a size of 0, 1 or x. `document.querySelector` accepts a CSS selector and only returns the first matching element or null. There's also `document.querySelectorAll` which is closer, but it also accepts a CSS selector (i.e. you'd have to pass `".p-count")` and also returns a list of elements.

Comment: @ChrisG I looked at your example. Thank you for that. I think I'm still confusing the class vs id selectors as well, which is then messing my JS selection up too.

Comment: The <p>...</p> in your HTML is parsed into an [HTMLParagraphElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLParagraphElement) and put into the DOM tree of elements. You can access its properties now, among them `.innerText`

Comment: You know CSS, so just forget about the getElement(s) methods and only use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`. That way you can use the selectors you know from CSS 1:1.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for providing all this information. I just "finished" learning the basics from codeacademy for the first time, and this is my first project. It didn't go through DOM manipulation at all, so I'm trying to pull info from many different places...

Comment: You're welcome. And JS in a browser context is at least 50% DOM manipulation... ;)

Comment: It's worth getting your head around the subtle distinction between the _markup_ (written in HTML, contains elements and attributes) and the _Document Object Model (DOM)_ (interacted with via JavaScript, has nodes and values). Any Web Document can be seen in terms of the _Markup_ (which is like text surrounded by punctuation) or the _DOM_ (which is like a computational object) - it is _both_ of these things simultaneously. Essentially, the DOM is a superposition over the Markup.

Answer (score 2):

Should you initialize variables? Yes. Always start from a known state.

But your `game` functions' variable declarations are *local to `game`*—the variables referenced elsewhere are operating on *global state* (i.e., `window`), not the variables `game` declares.

If functionality is going to be spread over multiple functions everything needs to refer to the *same thing*, regardless of how it's implemented. For example, you could have a class, you could create a closure over the game state and return functions that operate on it, etc.